# Active Directory RSAT not showing under Windows features

Tags: active-directory, windows-10

I have Windows 10 Pro installed as a virtual Machine in Esxi box , I wanted to configure AD in the same machine to authenticate user logins from other machines.

After installing 'RSAT Active Directory Domain Services and Lightweight Directory Service Tools ' , I am unable to get its display under Windows features as I want to turn ON that particular Windows feature.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0MeB.png)

Comment: This is what you downloaded?: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520 Have you rebooted, maybe?

Comment: I tried reboot several times already